# Parse arithmetic/boolean expression but skip capture

Tags: haskell, parsec

Given the following expression

```
x = a + 3 + b * 5
```

I would like to write that in the following data structure, where I'm only interested to capture the variables used on the RHS and keep the string intact. Not interesting in parsing a more specific structure since I'm doing a transformation from language to language, and not handling the evaluation

```
Variable "x" (Expr ["a","b"] "a + 3 + b * 5")
```

I've been using [this tutorial](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parsing_a_simple_imperative_language) as my starting point, but I'm not sure how to write an expression parser without `buildExpressionParser`. That doesn't seem to be the way I should approach this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you want to avoid buildExpressionParser, as it hides a lot of the complexity in parsing expressions with infix operators.  It is the *right* way to do things....

Sorry about that, but now that I got that nag out of the way, I can answer your question.

First, here is some background-

The main reason writing a parser for expressions with infix operators is hard is because of operator precedence.  You want to make sure that this

```
x+y*z
```

parses as this

```
  +
 / \
x   *
    /\  
   y  z
```

and not this

```
    *
   / \
  +   z
 / \
x   y
```

Choosing the correct parsetree isn't a very hard problem to solve....  But if you aren't paying attention, you can write some really bad code.  Why?  Performance....

The number of possible parsetrees, ignoring precedence, grows exponentially with the size of the input.  For instance, if you write code to try all possibilities then throw away all but the ones with the proper precedence, you will have a nasty surprise when your parser tackles anything in the real world (remember, exponential complexity often ain't just slow, it is basically not a solution at all....  You may find that you are waiting half an hour for a simple parse, no one will use that parser).

I won't repeat the details of the "proper" solution here (a google search will give the details), except to note that the proper solution runs at O(n) with the size of the input, and that buildExpressionParser hides all the complexity of writing such a parser for you.

---

So, back to your original question....

Do you need to use buildExpressionParser to get the variables out of the RHS, or is there a better way?

You don't *need* it....

Since all you care about is getting the variables used in the right side, you don't care about operator precedence.  You can just make everything left associative and write a simple O(n) parser.  The parsetrees will be wrong, but who cares?  You will still get the same variables out.  You don't even need a context free grammar for this, this regular expression basically does it

```
<variable>(<operator><variable>)*
```

(where `<variable>` and `<operator>` are defined in the obvious way).

However....

I wouldn't recommend this, because, as simple as it is, it still will be more work than using buildExpressionParser.  And it will be trickier to extend (like adding parenthesis).  But most important, later on, you may accidentally use it somewhere where you do need a full parsetree, and be confused for a while why the operator precedence is so completely messed up.

Another solution is, you could rewrite your grammar to remove the ambiguity (again, google will tell you how)....  This would be good as a learning exercise, but you basically would be repeating what buildExpressionParser is doing internally.